# How to read the starting in the command prompt jn Java

Tags: java, terminal, command-prompt, readline

I am wondering how I can read the starting line from the command prompt in Java.

For example if you run a Java program namned Test.java I usually writes:

```
java Test
```

, But if I write this in the command prompt(see below), I would like to read the "string" in the test.java-file when it starts:

```
java Test string
```

how can I in the test.java file get access of the string "string"?

I have tried:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
String text= in.nextLine();
```

but that only allows me to get access of the next thing that is written in the command prompt.

Comment: why do you need scanner for that ? You will have it in string array passed as a parameter into the main method!

Answer (score 1):

To read command line parameters you should use the `String[] args` argument of the main method not read from standard in.

Answer (score 1):

if you are inside main method then you can simply do as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
    System.out.println(args[i]);
}
```

because args will have all the command line arguments values after `java <class name>` command

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that Test class has a main method...

```
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }
```

The array passed in to main contains the arguments you pass on the command line...

```
args[0].equals("string") == true
```

Or do you want to get the entire command line that started the JVM?

Answer (score 0):

The command line arguments show up in the args[] array that is passed to the main method.  So to get the name of the file that was passed on the command line, you can just look at args[0]:

```
System.out.println(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String nextLine()
```

Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.

Since this method continues to search through the input looking for a line separator, it may buffer all of the input searching for the line to skip if no line separators are present.

> Scanner read becomes active when any inputs provided once java program started because of this reason it did not read the command prompt input but it is able to read next line to the command prompt. It did not bother the past input or input provide before scanner class comes into action what it cares the values provided once Scanner class in action.

Comment: Thanks unihedron.. If my answer give adequate information please upvote my answer.